# Overlap of two polytopes

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, polytopes

If two n-polytopes are described by its vertices in $R^n$. How to compute the vertices of their intersection polytope?

Comment: There is an algorithm, see [here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/C/lrs.html).

Answer (score 1):

The intersection can be computed using the so-called *vertex enumeration problem*. A detailed description can be found in the article [Frequently Asked Questions in Polyhedral Computation](ftp://ftp.math.ethz.ch/users/fukudak/reports/polyfaq040618.pdf) by Komei Fukuda, section 2.22 on page 13.